# How is Max going to get out of it at the end of Welcome to the Punch?

Tags: plot-explanation, welcome-to-the-punch

In the end of the film *Welcome To The Punch*, Max is left alone with the cops coming at him.

He's been framed for Sarah's murder. The only ones who could have done something to save Max are Jacob and Tom. Tom is dead, Jacob is on the run.

How does Max then prove his innocence?

Comment: Does the film say that he *does* get out of it? If it doesn't, and it doesn't show it, then it's entirely possible that he didn't.

Comment: He was concerned about being framed a few scenes before. Just didn't come up again...